# Any issues with swapping objects and thread safety?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, concurrency, thread-safety

Let's assume we have a property `List<Bar> Foo` that is being *read* by multiple threads.

Are there any issues that such a code:

```
Foo = GetNewFooList();
```

could cause?

PS 1: this question is out of curiosity, I don't have any particular code (yet)

PS 2: yep, I'm aware that 2 consecutive reads like `Foo[0]; Foo[0];` may return different results. It's an expected behaviour

PS 3: the question is more about unexpected exceptions or any kind *undefined behaviour* or any other side effects (not sure of what *undefined behaviour* could be in this case - and if I knew it I wouldn't ask the question)

Comment: Can you provide a more complete code example.  Depending on what, exactly you're doing, there could certainly be data consistency issues.

Comment: @Greg Prisament: I'm aware of data consistency issues, my question was more about fundamental issues, like unexpected exceptions or so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `GetFooList()` returns an empty list, then the second of two consecutive reads of `Foo[0]` could throw an exception. More generally, if you have:

```
int i = Foo.IndexOf(something);
Bar b1 = Foo[i];
Foo = GetNewFooList(); // happens asynchronously
Bar b2 = Foo[i];
```

The second will throw an exception if `i >= Foo.Count`. That is, if the call returns a shorter list.

If one thread is iterating over the list:

```
for (int i = 0; i < Foo.Count; ++i)
{
    // At this point, the other thread gets a new list,
    // whose Count <= i
    Bar b = Foo[i];  // throws an exception
    // whatever
}
```

Which is really just another manifestation of the first problem.

That's the only one I can think of offhand. You might be able to solve the loop problem with a `foreach`. I can't say for certain, though, that there aren't other problems lurking in the weeds.

Generally, if you have any code that expects `Foo` not to change between two references to it, that code is going to fail.

Comment: `Foo[0]` was given as an example and has nothing to do with concurrency, don't you agree? Well, it's still a data consistency issue, not much about some deeper issues (example of what I expect: iterating over modified collection would cause an exception)

Comment: "Generally, if you have any code that expects Foo not to change between two references to it, that code is going to fail." --- well, it could be solved easily: `var localFoo = Foo;` and then you can be sure `localFoo` isn't modified (following the original idea - that no one modifies it but swaps with another one)

Comment: @zerkms: You said, "may return different results", which is much different than throwing an exception.

Comment: "may return different results" --- a thrown exception is a result for me :-)

Comment: Yep, so it looks like a cheap lock-free solution then for small size collections. Isn't it?

Comment: @zerkms I don't see why the collection has to be small.  You are making a local copy of the *reference* to the list, not an actual copy of the list.

Comment: @Mike Clark: if you want to add an item to the list A using this solution - you need to **create a copy** B of it, add an item to B, then swap them.

Comment: @zerkms Yes -- and the way to create such a copy would be `var localFoo = new List(Foo); localFoo.Add(b); Foo = localFoo;`, not `var localFoo = Foo; localFoo.Add(b); Foo = localFoo;`.  Making a copy of the *list reference* helps you with the iteration problem, making a copy of the *list itself* helps you implement the *copy-on-write* concurrency strategy.

Comment: @Mike Clark: so? I don't see your point. "I don't see why the collection has to be small" --- because copying takes some time and memory. That's it.

Comment: @zerkms The point is nobody mentioned actually making a real copy of the list until I chimed in.  Up until then you guys were talking about making a copy of the *reference*, which is cheap and runs in constant time regardless of the size of the list, but doesn't achieve the same effect with regards to concurrency.  I wanted to point out the difference between copying the reference and copying the list.  There are differences regarding concurrent patterns and differences in copy expense.

Comment: @Mike Clark: "The point is nobody mentioned actually making a real copy" --- I mentioned it when I said "so it looks like a cheap lock-free solution then for small size collections". That's why I said "small size collections" because making a real copy takes some time and memory. We **DO REALIZE** the difference between copying and making another reference to the same reference type object.